# How to set yourself as a delegate class without affecting subsequent settings to delegate to other objects to implement delegate methods？

Tags: ios

I wrote a subclass of UITextView, and then I want to set the delegate to itself and implement some logic in the delegate method, but if I do this, I cannot reset the delegate to other objects。

```
open class TextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        delegate = self
    }

    // Implement some logic here
    public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textView: TextView = TextView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // set delegate 
            textView.delegate = self
        }
}

// Now I want to set UITextViewDelegate to ViewController
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
     // Implement some logic here
    public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    }
}
```

Are there any tricks to achieve this?

Comment: It's a serious problem; I've encountered the same dilemma recently. If this text view is for use solely within your app, you could make yourself the delegate, provide a sort of secondary delegate property, and forward messages to the other "delegate". You can actually automate that forwarding using Objective-C runtime messaging.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution.

```
class TextViewDelegateObject: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

    private(set) weak var realDelegate: AnyObject?
    init(realDelegate: AnyObject?) {
        self.realDelegate = realDelegate

    }


    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    // Complete some of your own logic here

    var flag = true
    // execute the real delegate method
    if let realDelegate = self.realDelegate as? UITextViewDelegate,
      let shouldChange = realDelegate.textView?(textView, shouldChangeTextIn: range, replacementText: text) {
      flag = shouldChange
    }
    return flag

  }

  // more UITextViewDelegate methods ...
}

open class TextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {


    private var delegateObject: TextViewDelegateObject?
    open override var delegate: UITextViewDelegate? {
        get { super.delegate }
        set {
            let delegateObject = TextViewDelegateObject(realDelegate: newValue)
            super.delegate = delegateObject
            self.delegateObject = delegateObject
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        delegate = nil
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textView: TextView = TextView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            textView.delegate = self
        }
}

// Now I want to set UITextViewDelegate to ViewController
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
     // Implement some logic here
    public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using `AnyObject?` for `realDelegate`. Just make it `UITextViewDelegate?`. Also, why are you setting `delegate = nil` in the initializer? If you do that, you're not using the `TextViewDelegatedObject`, and if you really do want it to be nil, you don't have to set it because it is nil by default. One last suggestion: instead of using a flag, you can just `return realDelegate?.textView?(textView, shouldChangeTextIn: range, replacementText: text) ?? true`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I will solve the problems you said.